# XCode hangs on 'Compile Bitcode' step for more than half an hour every time I build a project

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm

recently I notice that XCode takes a very considerable amount of time to build a project, between 20-30 minutes every time, even if I only change a few lines of code. Is there something wrong with my installation or configuration? Seems pretty abnormal, whereas Android Studio builds apks for release on the same computer in less than a minute.

I am using XCode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b) on a MacBook Pro 11,1, Late 2013, Quad Core i5 with 2.6 GHz.

Comment: When coding does the color coding for variables and functions flicker on and off?

Comment: You that they sometimes turn back into monochrome, like raw text?

Comment: Right, if they are doing that than you have an error in your code somewhere that xCode is having a hard time processing like a bad loop or a custom variable that has a long list of parameters needed being initialized.